# Deep linking not working in publisher App

Tags: java, android, android-studio, deep-linking

I have created a publisher app where I render ad-related tags. The ad that I render generally has clickThrough URLs like https://youtube.com or https://facebook.com.

When I click on my ad I want these links to open in-app instead of the browser.(On directly clicking these links as text, it is opening in-app)
Do I need to add any type of code for making this happen because I am in the idea that it should happen automatically?

I am new to android, so please let me know if you need any more details for better understanding in the comments.

**Edit** - Adding **AndroidManifest.xml**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
          xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
          package="com.iab.omid.sampleapp">
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.SYSTEM_ALERT_WINDOW" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET" />
    <application

        android:networkSecurityConfig="@xml/network_security_config"
        android:name=".AdApplication"
        android:allowBackup="false"
        android:icon="@mipmap/ic_launcher"
        android:label="@string/app_name"
        android:roundIcon="@mipmap/ic_launcher_round"
        android:supportsRtl="true"
        android:theme="@style/AppTheme"
        tools:ignore="GoogleAppIndexingWarning">
        <activity
            android:name=".AdListActivity"
            android:label="@string/app_name"
            android:theme="@style/AppTheme.NoActionBar"
            android:exported="true" >
            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN"/>

                <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER"/>
            </intent-filter>
            
        </activity>
        <activity
            android:name=".AdDetailActivity"
            android:label="@string/title_ad_detail"
            android:parentActivityName=".AdListActivity"
            android:theme="@style/AppTheme.NoActionBar"
            android:exported="false">
            <meta-data
                android:name="android.support.PARENT_ACTIVITY"
                android:value="com.iab.omid.sampleapp.AdListActivity"/>
        </activity>
        <activity android:name="com.squareup.leakcanary.internal.DisplayLeakActivity"
            android:exported="true"/>
    </application>

</manifest>
```

Comment: Have you done manifest configuration? or do you know deep link how does it work?

Comment: @HosseinAsadi I have added my current manifest config. Can you please let me know if I have missed anything necessary there?

Comment: see my below answer, you must first config deep link into manifest